# Problems with Google Maps online

Tags: javascript, html, css

With the example code taken from w3schools,
the google maps works perfect in my html editor but it does not work online.
What is the problem and how can I solve?

W3 example
http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_intro.asp

my code online,
view-source:http://www.joaocouto-espinho.com/places/sintra/castelo-mouros.html

Comment: Open the browser's error console. Look at the error messages.

Comment: You have `MissingKeyMapError`. click on the error in console.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your console. Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError

You will need to use map key. you can see detail here. Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys